# Canon AE-1 Shutter stays open until I pull the battery out

Tags: canon, battery, shutter

I have a very nice AE-1 with everything working, but the shutter stays open for seconds. Sometimes it won't close until I pull the battery out. The shutter speed setting has no effect. Any ideas?
Thanks! - Rien

Comment: Hi Rien and welcome to Photo.SE! When you mention `Sometime it won't close...` when is this `sometimes` happening? Just at random?

Comment: Can you please confirm if the shutter stays open or if it's just the mirror not returning?

Comment: Does the camera have a self timer, and is it on? Also, I remember a similar situation when the mirror would stay locked up if the battery was low.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have it on Auto mode in a low light situation, or your battery may be getting low.  Check those things first.
If it's not low light or battery you may need a partial "Clean, Lubricate, Adjust" (CLA) maintenance or a repair.

Comment: The Canon AE-1 is a shutter priority camera. Given Marinus H.B. Vesseur has correctly identified his camera, there is no automatic mode that would control the shutter speed.

Comment: Not is it's an AE-1 Program.   He's looking for possibilities and I am providing that.